# I am getting the following errors while trying to install PyQt and Scrapy in MS Windows through CMD

Tags: python, windows, pyqt, scrapy

PyQt installation error

Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement PyQt (from versions: )

No matching distribution found for PyQt

Scrapy installation error

> Command
>   "c:\users\tanuj.chhabra\appdata\local\programs\python\python36-32\python.exe
>   -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;file='C:\Users\TANUJ~1.CHH\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-di2wv0lk\Twisted\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
>   'open', open(file);code=f.read().replace('\r\n',
>   '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, file, 'exec'))" install --record
>   C:\Users\TANUJ~1.CHH\AppData\Local\Te
>   mp\pip-record-vkbbg2ax\install-record.txt
>   --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in C:\Users\TANUJ~1.CHH\AppData\Local\Temp\pip
>   -install-di2wv0lk\Twisted\

Comment: Hmm ... looks like your best bet is downloading the source and building it yourself. But i wonder why it looks like you tried to pip install twisted rather than pyqt oO

Comment: Could you please suggest how to do that? I tried pip install pyqt as well but that also gave the following error: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement pyqt (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for pyqt

Comment: How about: you go to [pyqt/download5](https://www.riverbankcomputing.com/software/pyqt/download5), get the windows source package and follow the steps in the README, which is contained in the zip file. (And if that doesn't work: maybe switch to a proper OS x] )

Comment: Sure, will try that. Thanks!